# Copying and Pasting Automation

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to use python to write a script that takes in an in.txt file and gets each line to copy and paste to a certain coordinate and click at a certain coordinate too.

Are there any modules that can help me accomplish this automation task?

Here is my pseudocode:

```
-get in file

-put lines into array

-for each line in the array

{
     copy it 
     paste to a certain coordinate
     click a certain coordinate
}
```

Comment: paste where and click on a certain coordinate is not very clear. What exactly are you trying to do with the content of the file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy to clipboard and let the script handle the extraction of the lines from the clipboard, you could look into pyperclip module.

But for your case, why don't you just use built-in functions, like

```
fileName = open(urlToFile)
fileNameContentString = fileName.read() #return a string of entire content
#or
fileNameContentList = fileName.readlines() #return a list of string of each line
#finally don't forget to close
fileName.close()

for line in fileNameContentList:
   print line
   # whatever else you would like to do with the line.
```